# How to display staffs who never approved an order in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i have these tables:

- tblstaff (staff_id, SName, Department)
- tblorder (order_id, orderdate, cus_id, tootalAmount, staff_id)

i want to display all names and department of staffs who did not approve an order. The code below shows me empty set.

```
SELECT s.SName, s.Department from tblstaff s 
INNER JOIN tblorder o
on s.staff_id=o.staff_id
WHERE o.order_id is Null;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Answer (score 0):

`inner join` will only give you results when items from table a and table b match. What you want is `left join`.

```
SELECT s.SName, s.Department 
from tblstaff s 
LEFT JOIN tblorder o
on s.staff_id=o.staff_id
WHERE o.order_id is Null;
```

This will give you all results from `tblstaff`, even if they have no match in `tblorder`.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation and help, it works.

Comment: @StephenOkwechime You're welcome. Since you found my answer helpful, you could mark it as "answer" by pressing the check mark on the left.